# Display images in react fetched from Pinata

Tags: javascript, html, ipfs

I would like to retrieve an image from Pinata and display it in a page in react.
This is the image:

```
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmc3gWiMKiRhnc61oSL3nR4Dg5NfJArNiQ2DZA6wpppKT4
```

How can I retrieve this image and display in a

```
<img>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the image url if it's fixed. Or pass a imageUrlFetched variable if you're fetching it from an API

```
<img src="https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmc3gWiMKiRhnc61oSL3nR4Dg5NfJArNiQ2DZA6wpppKT4" />
<img src={imageUrlFetched} />
```

It renders it correctly in your webpage